# Microsoft Excel Application entry is missing in DCOM Config

Tags: c#, office-interop, com-interop, excel-interop, dcom

The entry for "Microsoft Excel Application" is not there in DCOM Config (tried in both 32-bit and 64-bit). How can I make it shows up there? I have Microsoft Office installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Excel Application" in dcomcnfg not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993253/microsoft-excel-application-in-dcomcnfg-not-exist)

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot find 'Microsoft Excel Application' in either 32-bit or 64-bit DCOMCNFG, you might go into registry to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/AppID and find the CLSID for your version of Excel (Excel 2013 has an AppID of {00020812-0000-0000-C000-000000000046})

Check that the (Default) REG_SZ for this key has a value set for it.

If not, change the default value to "Microsoft Excel Application" and after relaunching DCOMCNFG you should see "Microsoft Excel Application" in the DCOM tree.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed error `80070005 Access is denied.`. I now have error `80080005 Server execution failed`, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have restarted since the install, this page explains how to attempt to re-register the COM server: [TechNet Entry on Excel DCOM Config](http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/11/12/microsoft-excel-does-not-appear-in-dcom-configuration-snap-in.aspx).

> From a command prompt, navigate to where the Excel.exe is located and
>   re-register the application. On a 64-bit machine, this is located (by
>   default) under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14 for
>   Office 2010 and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12 for
>   Office 2007.
>
> 1. Open a command prompt – START, RUN, type CMD.EXE but don’t hit ENTER just yet
> 2. Find CMD.EXE in the ‘All Programs” list. Right click it and left click on “Run as administrator”
> 3. This should open a command prompt. Now, type the following:
>
>    ```
>    CD\
>    ```
>
>    And hit ENTER. Then type:
>
>    ```
>    CD C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14
>    ```
>
>    And hit ENTER. Then type:
>
>    ```
>    EXCEL.EXE –REGSERVER
>    ```
>
>    And hit ENTER
>
> * Note, for Microsoft Word the CMD would be: `WINWORD.EXE –REGSERVER`

Comment: If I do that Excel thinks -REGSERVER is a file passed as parameter to be opened, then it opens and gives error :(

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **Microsoft Excel 2016** on a **Windows Server 2016 Machine**, you need to run "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Excel.exe -REGSERVER**" with admin privileges. This command creates the DCOM entries.

I adapted that from the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/microsoft-excel-or-microsoft-word-does-not-appear-in-dcom-configuration-snap-in

I suggest you to log-in to Windows with the service user and run Excel one time to have a user profile set up and Excel registered to that user. Also you might need to set some Trust Center settings to allow for example working with old XLS 4.0 Formats, and so on. As these settings are bound to the user and not the local machine.

After that, it is essential (strange as it seems) to create two new folders called "Desktop" beneath "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile" and also "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile". When created give the executing user Read/Create/Change permissions on the root folders "..\systemprofile" to allow the running user to access the directory's tree.
The creation of the two Desktop folders was key for my InterOp to work!

See also: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/01ef550d-22e8-4d34-804f-b998bbb0a585/microsoft-excel-cannot-access-the-file-822082308221-there-are-several-possible-reasons

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to **unregister** the component first.

First run:

```
EXCEL.EXE -UNREGSERVER
```

then:

```
EXCEL.EXE -REGSERVER
```

Answer (score -1):

Start DCOMCNFG in 32-bit Mode:

```
DCOMCNFG -32
```

Then located under:

**Component Services \ My Computer \ DCOM Config \ Microsoft Excel Application**