# Microsoft Word application missing in DCOMCNFG

Tags: ms-word, windows-server-2012, dcom

I am trying to edit security properties to Word DCOM but i can't find it (neither by application name nor cslid).
I tested all the answers given for this problem, but still no luck.

I am working with Windows Server 2012 (64bits) and Microsoft Office 64bits.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993253/microsoft-excel-application-in-dcomcnfg-not-exist