# Weird issue when trying to open Excel Application from VBScript especially when the script is not running with elevated access/privileges

Tags: excel, vbscript, runtime-error, windows-11, excel.application

As I mentioned in the Q-title, I have a VBScript which I am sure was working fine in Windows 10 with `Microsoft® Excel® LTSC MSO (Version 2205 Build 16.0.15225.20278) 64-bit` Excel version and once I made sure that `ClickToRunSvc` service was running, and then when I ran this VBScript(without any elevation) it did open any Excel secured sheet with password, so that I didn't have to enter password everytime I wanted to open the sheet(I know not very secure, but this is my system behind firewall, so not much worried about it there).:

```
Sub OpenChosenLockedSheet(ChosenFile)
    AdminElevate
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.SendKeys "% x" : objExcel.Visible = True : objExcel.SendKeys "% x"
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").AppActivate GetObject(, "Excel.Application").Caption
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ChosenFile, , , ,"<password>")
    Set objExcel = Nothing : Set objWorkbook = Nothing
End Sub
```

But now after fully upgrading the OS to Windows 11, this same above script, running with same Office Excel version, doesn't open the `Excel.Application` at all and throws the below(also very infamous) error, unless I self-elevate the above script(that's why `AdminElevate` is uncommented) and open the secured sheet:

```
Error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'Excel.Application'
Code: 800A01AD
```

So my query: Is this part of bigger change Microsoft made when it rolled out Windows 11 and I missed or there needs to be some extra coding or quick-fix done to make this script work without admin-elevation ? Anyone feel free to help out.

Comment: So, just to be clear if you run the script elevated it runs on Windows 11?

Comment: Would check [Component Services to make sure you have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32993253/692942) to create the `Excel.Application` without Administrator rights.