# How to find out Application AppID \ CLSID IN Windows Registry \ DCOM Config

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dcom, clsid

continuing from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710299/microsoft-excel-application-entry-is-missing-in-dcom-config):

How can I find the GUID for other applications or even excel if the guy from the thread above didn't mention it?

Let's say I missing from dcom (both regular and 32bit version) in server 2012R2DC with office 2010 32Bit the Microsoft Excel Application and Microsoft Word Application (or other software need to give dcom permissions to) and I want to fix the name in dcom like the guy mention in the thread, how can I find the AppID\CLSID?

Is the AppID is the same GUID as the CLSID?

Thank you,

Comment: That is chicken-and-egg, you don't generally know the guid until the app is installed.  It is the installer's job to create that key, not yours.  That entering it by hand then caused a runtime error is the expected outcome, he simply did not have Office installed.